# symfony/skeleton with version 5.4 not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm triying to create a new symfony project for class work and when I try to run the command to create it:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"^5.4" 2023-truiter-symfony
```

Gives me the next error:

[symfony error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp6E9.png)

My PHP version is 8.1.12 and my composer version is 2.5.1

I've been trying to create a new symfony project without specifying the version and it works, but I would like that when the project is created it has the version ^5.4

Comment: what about `symfony/skeleton:5.*` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Can you share more details? Are you sure you are **reallly** using the caret in front of `5.4` when executing the command?

Comment: If I use the command `symfony/skeleton:5.*` it gives me the same error.

I'm totally sure the command is correctly written Nico, as you can see in the screenshot I let you here
[https://i.gyazo.com/0be9710edcad77a7162bc752793ddccc.png]

Comment: Pretty strange that you typed  `^5.4`, but the output omits the caret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution to the problem, I have installed CLI Symfony following the instructions from:

https://symfony.com/download

Once installed the problem when creating the project with the "^5.4" version has been solved.